# How do I launch the email app with the "to" field pre-filled?

Tags: android, email, android-activity, android-intent

I tried this code which I found here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "testemail@gmail.com", null)); startActivity(intent);
```

But I get a message on the screen which reads "Unsupported Action". Any ideas of how to get this working?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this [snippet](https://web.archive.org/web/20090416054511/http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/29/) by [dylan](https://web.archive.org/web/20090415103022/http://www.androidsnippets.org/users/dylan/):

```
/* Create the Intent */
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

/* Fill it with Data */
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");

/* Send it off to the Activity-Chooser */
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Key pieces: using `EXTRA_EMAIL` for your addresses and using `createChooser()` in case the user has more than one email client configured.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) I did try something like that initially but it just pulled up some messaging screen and not the email app. I think that was because, at the time, I didn't have an email account set up in the emulator?

Comment: What did you use the final keyword?  Does that result in some sort of optimization I'm unaware of?

Comment: I didn't write the snippet. Personally, I probably would not have used the final keyword there.

Comment: Original author probably used the final emailIntent var inside some listener but eventually changed the approach and forgot to remove the final keyword? Anyway, that's just my guess. :)

Comment: It says "No apps can perform that action"

Answer (score 5):

Did you try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
    Uri.parse("mailto:testemail@gmail.com")
);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, still get the message:

Unsupported Action
This action is not currently supported.

In a Toast-like bubble. Do I need to set up something in the manifest to let my app use this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problems here are that you're running on the official emulator and your intent isn't matching anything.

From my testing, this is a problem that happens when the intent's URI (from `setData()`) doesn't match anything and you're running on one of the official Android emulators. This doesn't seem to happen on real devices, so it shouldn't be a real-world problem.

You can use this code to detect when this is going to happen before you launch the intent:

```
ComponentName emailApp = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager());
ComponentName unsupportedAction = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.fallback/.Fallback");
boolean hasEmailApp = emailApp != null && !emailApp.equals(unsupportedAction);
```

(The name of the activity that shows the "Unsupported action" action method is `com.android.fallback.FallbackActivity`.)

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin use this extention

```
fun Context.sendEmailTo(email:String){
Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
    data = Uri.parse("mailto:$email")
    startActivity(this)
}
```

}